# git bash command not responding

Tags: git, command, comments

I am running some commands in git bash, but git bash does not respond to these commands now.  The probable reason is that there is a git commit before, with the comments in single quotes; the comments should be double quotes.

Now, it seems the only way is to close git bash and restart.

Is there some way I could continue without closing the git bash?

I am using Dell, Windows 10 64-bit.

[image]

Comment: `ctrl + c` is the most used task-killing command for command

Answer (score 5):

You aren't closing out the comment with an end quote. So all new lines are considered part of the comment still.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the unmatched quote in your `commit` command,

1) The `commit` command has not started executing, and

2) The subsequent lines you've entered are being interpreted as part of a commit message

So you don't have to kill the bash shell.  Just hit +C to abort the command in progress and start over, remembering to include the close-quote at the end of the commit message.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing Ctrl+C interrupts the currently running command. Find out more here [https://initialcommit.com/blog/how-to-paste-in-git-bash#:~:text=Many%20new%20users%20try%20to,such%20as%20Ctrl%2BC%20](https://initialcommit.com/blog/how-to-paste-in-git-bash#:%7E:text=Many%20new%20users%20try%20to,such%20as%20Ctrl%2BC%20)).

Comment: It is a good idea to extract the main concept/explanation from links and only leave said links as the source.